# return file id after resumable upload finished with google drive

Tags: node.js, express, google-drive-api

I'm integrating google drive API in my application and I'm using resumable upload approach
but i can't figure out how can i get file id after upload finished in the resumable response body

here is my code to get resumable uri

```
const body = JSON.stringify({
        name:file.originalname,
        mimeType:file.mimetype,
        parents:[parent folder id]
    })

    const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable'
    const option = {
        method: 'post',
        body,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
         'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        }
    }
    const response = await fetch(url, option)
    const resumableURI = response.headers.get('location')
```

and this is my code to upload my file chunks

```
const options = {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
            'Content-Length': file.size,
            'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end - 1}/${length}`,
            },
            body: file.buffer, // contents of the chunk
        };
 
        const response  = await fetch(RESUBMALEURI, options)
```

this is the response i got from api after upload complete

```
response: Response {
size: 0,
timeout: 0,
[Symbol(Body internals)]: { body: [PassThrough], disturbed: false, error: null },
[Symbol(Response internals)]: {
     url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files? 
           uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ADPycdvajyaSOgYUjPmFgZIbi- 
          vbjM0U7xHe0yLy1eahXOC1Zq06K7ZFN2O0c_IKRdEJfa-WFc8DwE814cjV0nhCv0U',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: [Headers],
     counter: 0
    }
}
```

}

is there any option i can add to request of resubmale uri or upload request itself to return the file id in the end

Comment: In the case of resumable upload, when the file is completely uploaded, the file metadata of the uploaded file is returned at the last request. When you completely uploaded the file, what result did you obtain?

Comment: this is what i thought in first place but when i inspect the response i got no metadata at all

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply of `this is what i thought in first place but when i inspect the response i got no metadata at all`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate this. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly replicate your situation using your showing script, I would like to think of the reason of the issue. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply aplogize for my poor skill again.

Comment: i updated my question with the response i got but i would like to thank you from my heart that you took from your time to replay to my question, thank you so much

Comment: It would be easer if you were using the offfical google apis node.js client library.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the response value. From your response value, I proposed a modification point as an answer by guessing your actual script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your actual script, I apologize.

Comment: @DaImTo, i would be thankful if you can direct me to the client library that handle resumbale upload because i tried to search for that but i only found rest api that can handle this kind of upload 
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I saw your script and your additional response value, I'm worried that you might have retrieved the response value using `console.log(response)` from `const response  = await fetch(RESUBMALEURI, options)`. If my understanding is correct, in that case, unfortunately, such a response is obtained.

If your script for the resumable upload the file works fine and the upload is completely finished, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const response  = await fetch(RESUBMALEURI, options)
```

#### To:

```
const response  = await fetch(RESUBMALEURI, options)
const res = await response.json();
console.log(res);
// console.log(res.id); // If you want to retrieve only the file ID, you can use this.
```

- By this modification, when at the last request, you can obtain the following value.

  ```
    {
      kind: 'drive#file',
      id: '###',
      name: '###',
      mimeType: '###'
    }
  ```

#### Note:

- By the way, in your 1st request, the location is put in the variable of `resumableURI`. But in your script for uploading the file content, you are using the `RESUBMALEURI` as the endpoint. If your actual situation uses this, please modify this. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Comment: thank you so much for your help , it really works, i tried to do this on the response of obtaining resumable uri but it gave me undefined , that what makes me never think of this easy thing to do

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelrahman Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.